# What does a recipe mean in the Symfony PHP framework?

Tags: php, symfony

I jsut started learning about the framework symfony

What does a recipe mean in the Symfony PHP framework?

what is a flex ?
Update :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/flex_recipes.html#flex-recipes-and-aliases

And second, Flex installs a recipe for symfony/twig-bundle. What's a recipe? It's a way for a library to automatically configure itself by adding and modifying files. Thanks to recipes, adding features is seamless and automated: install a package and you're done!

Answer (score 4):

A recipe is a **file** returned by Symfony Flex which contains information (instructions) about how to modify the `require`, `update`, and `remove` commands of Composer. Essentially, recipes enable Symfony to automate the installation, update or removal of plugins in Symfony applications. For clarity, plugins are called [bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html) in Symfony lingo.

Symfony Flex is a Composer plugin designed for Symfony. This plugin helps to automate the installation, update or removal of Symfony bundles. Prior to Symfony Flex, after installation of a bundle for instance, you may need to perform additional manual configurations in some Symfony files in order to make use of the bundle in your application. With Flex, you install a bundle and Symfony automatically updates your file system and your bundle is ready for use in your application

Symfony flex also helps to install Symfony bundles using aliases for the specific bundles. For instance, prior to Symfony Flex, to install the SwiftmailerBundle, you have to execute `composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` but with Symfony Flex, there is an alias `composer require mailer` which installs the same bundle.

So back to **Recipes** as files. Let's consider an example of the installation of the SwiftmailerBundle. If Symfony Flex is installed, before the Symfony application tries to execute `composer require mailer`, it first sends that command to the Symfony Flex server. In this case, Symfony Flex recognizes that `composer require mailer` is an alias for `composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` so Symfony Flex will return a file (called a **Recipe**) to the Symfony application. This recipe will contain the actual composer command `composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` to install the bundle, in addition to other post installation instructions for that bundle (if any).

Note that without Symfony Flex, the Symfony application will simply execute the command `composer require mailer` which will return an error because composer does not recognize a package with such installation command.

An example post installation instruction could instruct the Symfony application to modify a configuration file in the application with some configuration instructions, in order to get the bundle ready for use. This means the developer doesn't need to manually go to the configuration file and make changes in order to use the bundle, as was the case before Symfony Flex.

From Symfony 4.0, Flex is used by default (though optional). More information on [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex.html)

Answer (score 1):

From [flex.symfony.com](https://flex.symfony.com/):

> Symfony Flex is the way to manage Symfony applications.
>
> It is based on Symfony Recipes, which are a set of automated
>   instructions to integrate third-party packages into Symfony
>   applications.

**My own explaination:**

With Composer you are able to add code components (bundles) to your Symfony project. Except the php code you have to add configuration, routes and assets for example in different configuration files or direcories. With "Flex recipes" this may happen automatically. This makes installing 3th party bundles more easy and quicker.

Comment: so recipes mean a set of pacckeges that can help me for my development?

Comment: No the recipes are (optional) part of the packages that will run during installation. So 1st the package itself will be installed by composer and then 2nd the recipe will be executed to add configuration, and copying necessary files to your webroot. (think about css, javascript, fonts and images)

Comment: i asked in another forum and one said that recipe are test units ? is that correct?

Comment: Check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/flex_recipes.html#flex-recipes-and-aliases